# Azure Data Explorer oneclick Ingest from blob container (UI)

Tags: azure, containers, blob, azure-data-explorer, ingest

I'm trying to configure and use the Azure Data Explorer OneClick Ingest from blob container (continous ingest).
Whatever I try the URL is never accepted, I always end up with this error:
*Invalid URL. Either the URL leads to a blob instead of a container, or the permissions are incorrect. If you just grant permission, please wait couple of minutes and try again.*

[image]

The URL I'm using follow that pattern:
https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sp=rl&st=2022-04-26T22:01:42Z&se=2032-04-27T06:01:42Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=Z4Mlh7s5%2Fm1890kdfzlkYLSIHHDdGJmTSyYXVYsHdn01o%3D

I'm probably missing something, either in the URL syntax ou SAS generation.

Has anyone successfully used it? Any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Works like magic. What happens when you try the "Select container" option instead of the "Add URL" option?

Comment: Same error message....
Is there a requirement on the storage account? I have a std and both are in the same resource group.

Comment: What is the type of the storage?

Comment: It's a standard, LRS, General Purpose v2.

I also tried to ingest the blob in Python script, and I get this error:

Failed to download blob: Access to persistent storage path https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/release-deployments.json' was denied (operation 'BlobPersistentStorageFile.DownloadToFileAsync').

In the script I authenticated with a user assigned managed identity.
I gave both the user assigned managed identity and the Adx Cluster Managed Identity, the permission "Blob Storage Data Contrbutor" on the storage container

Comment: When I tested it earlier today I created the SAS based on the account key

Comment: Did you generate your SAS URL with List & Read permissions for the required container?

Comment: Thanks David and atefsawaed, see my solution below :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what was the issue.
Probably due to the security in place on my Storage account I had to create in Azure Data Explorer Networking panel, a Managed private enpoint, pointing to my storage resource (and then approve that endpoint in the storage account Networking)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/security-network-managed-private-endpoint-create